# Can humans surpass AI in game-playing?

Tags: game-ai, human-activity-recognition

In the realm of game-playing, such as in the cases of AlphaGo and Deep Blue, can humans ultimately surpass AI in skill? Despite the current dominance of machine learning, what factors may contribute to humans eventually catching up to, or even exceeding, the capabilities of AI game players?

For example, can AI-assisted training and a deeper understanding of how AI works provide effective approaches for humans to improve their game-playing abilities? What are the limitations of these methodologies and what other methods may be required?

Answer (score 1):

Humans already *do* "surpass" AI in game-playing. AI-agents' difficulty at playing Montezuma's Revenge is an example. The question is usually the opposite: can AI surpass humans in game-playing skills? Hence the research dedicated to game-playing AI. The examples you provide are clear evidence that this is indeed possible, although for the moment not universal.

As for your second question, indeed there has already been a case where adversarial policies discovered by AI were used by a human to beat KataGo at the game of Go. See https://goattack.far.ai/human-evaluation. I'd recommend reading that paper and taking a dive into their related work if you're interested in this topic, there are references to other methods and limitations in the literature.

The rest of your question is asking for speculative answers about the future, which I have opinions on but will refrain from sharing here since that would be off-topic.